# how to run an function if other function return true on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 inline function calls on focus out event.

I want 2nd function run if 1st function return true without calling the 2nd funtion inside 1st function.

Inside this string `01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0` in brackets is available stock quantity.

i have tried the following code but output is not coming.

```js
function checkStockAvailable(batchNo, qty) {
  var startpos = batchNo.indexOf("( ");
  var endpos = batchNo.indexOf(" )");
  var stockQty = batchNo.substring(startpos + 2, endpos);
  if (qty > stockQty) {
    alert("Entered quantity can not be greater than stock quantity, please try again.");
    return false;
  }
  if (qty <= stockQty) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="10" onfocusout="if((return checkStockAvailable('01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0', $(this).val())) == true){saveDetailData('1',$(this).val(),'columnName' )})">
```

no output shows

Comment: Add the minimal required HTML to run your function.

Comment: You're comparing strings. You need to convert them to integers first.

Comment: You `onfocosout` handler contains code that is not Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript number comparison fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259014/javascript-number-comparison-fails)

Comment: There's also an error related to your `onfocusout` code; take a look at your browser's console.

Comment: thats why I have asked question, so that i get to know where is error and how to solve it @Herohtar

Comment: You need to learn how to debug to find the errors on your own. The first step is to look at your browser's console to see what error messages are showing up. If you don't understand why at that point, you should include them in your question.

Comment: I know how to debug, i am asking for a new way which i.e ** to run 2nd function if 1st function return true inline**

Comment: The code in `onfocusout` has multiple issues; it should not contain the `return` keyword (if you run the snippet and trigger the focus out you will see the error message `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'return'`). It also has mismatched parentheses. This is a valid expression: `if((checkStockAvailable('01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0', $(this).val())) == true){saveDetailData('1',$(this).val(),'columnName' )}`

Comment: $(this) should select the actual element but maybe better to "separates all the JavaScript code from the HTML and is the basis of jQuery", cited from: https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-dollar-sign-mean-in-jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function function1(batchNo, qty) {
  var startpos = batchNo.indexOf("( ");
  var endpos = batchNo.indexOf(" )");
  var stockQty = batchNo.substring(startpos + 2, endpos);
  if (qty > stockQty) {
    alert("Entered quantity can not be greater than stock quantity, please try again.");
    return false;
  }
  if (qty <= stockQty) {
    return true;
  }
}

function function2(a,b,c){
    alert('yes came in function 2');
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" value="10" onfocusout="function1('01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0','10') && function2('4','5','6')"/>
```

You can simplify the call by doing it like this

```
onfocus="function1() && function2()"
```

This will run the function2 if function1 returns a truthy value, and ignore function2 if function1 returns a false value.

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadadil/w0n86dyu/10/). Try changing the return value from function1 to see the effect.

Comment: i wrote this `onfocusout="checkStockAvailable(\'01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0\') && saveDetailData('.$detail->rowId.',$(this).val(),\'columnName\' )"` not working

Comment: @Danial212k WHat is the error that you see in the console Can you make up a JsFiddle for your problem?

Comment: it is not coming in function1() if i do alert('hello') in function 1 it does not do that, i wrote script of my code you can put values in batchNo and qty to check the code

Comment: The problem is you are cramping too much inside your functions. Your function calls should be simple just passing the data. All other operations should be handled inside the function and not in HTML event binding. Please create a fiddle then I can have a look at the problem

Comment: i dont know how to create fiddle, function1 passing 2 values, and function2 passing 3 values, in simple see this `onfocusout="checkStockAvailable('01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0', 10) && saveDetailData('1.',$(this).val(),'qty' )"`

Comment: i have to implement this on many pages thats why i can't change the code and call 2nd function in 1st function, i just want to put 1st function on every page so that if it returns true then run 2nd function

Comment: @Danial212k Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadadil/w0n86dyu/10/  also updated my answer with this

Comment: @Danial212k That will work, you just have to select the script to be rendered in the head tag before the HTML element is rendered. Please have a look in the console. It throws up errors. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/shahzadadil/sg95q8bv/1/

Comment: Click button nr 7 from left

Comment: your code works but please tell me why my code does not work, this is my code `onfocusout="checkStockAvailable(\'01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0\', $(this).val()) && saveDetailData('.$detail->id.',$(this).val(),\'qty\' )"`

Comment: only my savedetaildata function works with my code not checkstockavailable

Comment: @Danial212k As pointed out earlier, you are doing too much in HTML event binding. There are all sorts of things like escape characters which are not required. Then you have referenced jQUery using $ which is not defined at that point. If you did basic debugging of your code and inspected the console, you would know. I suggest you brush up your fundamentals of web development and how to debug on browsers.

Comment: the function on focusout is in php echo"<input type='number' value='10' onfocusout="checkStockAvailable(\'01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0\', $(this).val()) && saveDetailData('.$detail->id.',$(this).val(),\'qty\' )"" the 2nd function works perfectly but the 1st function does not work, your answer is accurate which i wanted, but please fix this part of code so that it goes inside checkStockAvailable function

Comment: @Danial212k remove the \ escape characters and load jquery in the head tag of the html, before this HTML is rendered. Though that is not a good way.

Comment: without \' it will not consider the text as a string and on top i have obviously already linked jquery thats why function2 works

Comment: @Danial212k Can you please debug your code in a browser and look into the error. I do not have access to your code so I cannot tell you what the exact issue is or the error is.

Comment: I am really sorry your code works i was checking on other page and wrote code on other page xxdd

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) with additional information and use this for a check.

```js
function checkStockAvailable(element) {
    var qty = +element.value,
        stockQty = +element.dataset.stockQty;

    console.log(qty, stockQty);
    if (qty <= stockQty) return true;
    console.log("Entered quantity can not be greater than stock quantity, please try again.");
}
```

```html
<input
    type="number"
    value="10"
    onfocusout="checkStockAvailable(this)"
    data-batch-no="01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 1 )0"
    data-stock-qty="1"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" value="10" onfocusout="if(f1()){f2()}">
<script>
  function f1() {
    return true;
  }

  function f2() {
    alert(4);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `onfocusout= "func1() && func()"` (as answered by @Shahzad )

`func1()` will be used for your conditional statement, and `func2()` will be dependent on `func1()`

If you are still facing issue, there might be some suntax issue.

```js
 function uppercase() {
    var x = document.getElementById("tText");
   x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
  }
  
  function checkBoolean(){
  return true;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tText" value="test" onfocusout="checkBoolean() && uppercase()">
```